# Can't use 2 digit numbers in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

this codes works perfectly for one digit numbers but when 2 digit numbers are used the error below is shown... Could anyone please help me fix this? :)

## Code

```
import sqlite3

connie = sqlite3.connect('pb.db')
c = connie.cursor()
test = 11
real = (str(test))
c.execute("""
SELECT result FROM results
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = results.user_id
WHERE users.id = (?)
""",real)

result_list = c.fetchall()

for result in result_list:
    print(result[0])


connie.close()
```

## Error

```
"C:\Users\britsge\OneDrive - Iona College\Year 11\DSO\PowerballSite\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/britsge/OneDrive - Iona College/Year 11/DSO/PowerballSite/db-select-ingredient-list.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/britsge/OneDrive - Iona College/Year 11/DSO/PowerballSite/db-select-ingredient-list.py", line 11, in <module>
    """,real)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

Comment: `.execute()` expects an iterable (list, tuple) or a dictionary as parameters. You give it a string, which it interprets as an iterable with 2 characters. Just change `, real)` to `, (real,))` and it will work as expected. (barring other errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to .execute() needs to be a sequence. For example, you could pass a list or a tuple. Here is how to make it a tuple:

Example:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO images VALUES(?)', (img,))
```

In your case: Only takes two arguments.

- It will iterate the "array"-object and match ? in the sql-string.(with sanity checks to avoid sql-injection)
- change , real) to , (real,))

  cursor.execute(sql,array)

Yours:

```
c.execute("""SELECT result FROM results INNER JOIN users ON users.id = results.user_id WHERE users.id = (?) """,real)
```

Change it to:

```
c.execute("SELECT result FROM results INNER JOIN users ON users.id = results.user_id WHERE users.id = (?) ", change ,(real,))
```